# NameError: global name 'QgsDataSourceURI' is not defined

Tags: postgis, pyqgis

Following on from my previous question I cannot seem to get my function to run using script runner in QGIS. However, if i type then out in the Python Console then they work and load the layer in question.

Is it something to do with how i! am using the run_script function at the bottom of my code?

[image: line 19 is not defined...]

Comment: This screen shot is fairly hard to read. Pasting the code and formatting it would help :D.

Comment: Thankyou, but I have moved onto a much more difficult issue now. So no doubt I will be creating a new question on here as I need to create my dialog box using Qt4 Designer, which is easier said that done as a newbie :|